# Running Eclipse on Mac with two users

Tags: eclipse, macos

I have installed Eclipse on my MacBook Pro (with Leopard) under one user and everything works. When I switch my user and try to run Eclipse I get an error message saying to look at the log. Here is that log file:

```
!SESSION 2009-06-08 15:28:17.204 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20090211-1700
java.version=1.5.0_16
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=carbon, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/work/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws carbon -arch x86 -keyring /Users/work/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility 4 0 2009-06-08 15:28:28.908
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.CompatibilityActivator.stop() of bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.suspendBundle(PackageAdminImpl.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.processDelta(PackageAdminImpl.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.doResolveBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl$1.run(PackageAdminImpl.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:613)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.CompatibilityHelper.getPluginDescriptor(CompatibilityHelper.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.CompatibilityActivator.stop(CompatibilityActivator.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1050)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:1046)
    ... 8 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.CompatibilityHelper.getPluginDescriptor(CompatibilityHelper.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.plugins.CompatibilityActivator.stop(CompatibilityActivator.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1050)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.suspendBundle(PackageAdminImpl.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.processDelta(PackageAdminImpl.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.doResolveBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl$1.run(PackageAdminImpl.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:613)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2009-06-08 15:28:33.910
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.0.4.v20081027-2115.jar" by thread "Start Level Event Dispatcher".
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1144)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.suspendBundle(PackageAdminImpl.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.processDelta(PackageAdminImpl.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.doResolveBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl$1.run(PackageAdminImpl.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:613)
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    ... 8 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1144)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.suspendBundle(PackageAdminImpl.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.processDelta(PackageAdminImpl.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.doResolveBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl$1.run(PackageAdminImpl.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:613)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.500
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.generator.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.getConfiguration(EclipseAppHandle.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.713
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.713
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.support.firefox_1.0.103.v200810021840.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.support.firefox 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.714
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.714
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.help_3.3.102.v20081014_34x.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.714
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.714
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jst.jee_1.0.103.v200901220530.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jst.jee 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.714
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.715
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.search_3.4.1.r341_v20080813-0800.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.search 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.715
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.715
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.sse.core_1.1.303.v200901290024.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.715
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.715
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.rse.subsystems.processes.dstore_2.1.0.v20080604.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.rse.subsystems.processes.dstore 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.715
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.716
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.debug.ui_3.4.2.v20090110_r342.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.debug.ui 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.716
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.716
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.3.103.v20081027_34x.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.forms 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.716
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.716
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.preview_1.0.100.v200805140145.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.server.preview 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.716
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.716
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.wsi.ui_1.0.400.v200805140300.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.wsi.ui 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.717
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.717
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.net_1.0.0.I20080605.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.net 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.717
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.717
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.dstore.core_3.0.3.v200902101918.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.dstore.core 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.717
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.717
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.xml.query_1.0.0.v200808140615.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.xml.query 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.717
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.718
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.mysql_1.0.2.v200810160130.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.mysql 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.718
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.718
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.command.env.core_1.0.204.v200805140020.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.command.env.core 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.718
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.718
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.rse.services.files.ftp_3.0.1.v200808191815.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.rse.services.files.ftp 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.718
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.718
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.lexer_1.0.1.v200811081015.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.lexer 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.719
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.719
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ant_2.4.0.v200902171115.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.emf.ant 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.719
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.719
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.http.core_1.0.100.v200805140145.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.server.http.core 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.719
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.720
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui_3.1.1.v20090411-0400-e3x.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.720
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.720
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query_1.0.1.v200810291500.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.720
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.720
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.views.log_1.0.0.v20080803-1700.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.views.log 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.721
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.721
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.ui_1.0.1.R200809220400.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.ui 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.721
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.721
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.emf.mapping_2.4.0.v200902171115.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.emf.mapping 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.721
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.721
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core_1.1.103.v200902042324.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.722
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.722
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.wsi_1.0.205.v200805140300.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.wsi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.722
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.722
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.ws.service.policy.ui_1.0.2.v200809031518.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.ws.service.policy.ui 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.722
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.722
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.emf.importer.ecore_2.4.0.v200902171115.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.emf.importer.ecore 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.722
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.723
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.rse.subsystems.shells.dstore_2.1.0.v20080604.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.rse.subsystems.shells.dstore 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.723
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.723
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.200.v20080508/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.723
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.723
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.gathering_1.0.1.R200809220400.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.gathering 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.723
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.723
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.snippets_1.1.200.v200805140415.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.common.snippets 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.724
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.724
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.postgresql_1.0.1.v200805152355.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.postgresql 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.724
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.724
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jst.ws.consumption_1.0.307.v200811220753/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jst.ws.consumption 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.724
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.724
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.xsd.edit_2.4.0.v200902171115.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.xsd.edit 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.725
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.725
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.internet.cache_1.0.301.v200805140020.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.internet.cache 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.725
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.725
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sap.maxdb_1.0.0.v200805152355.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sap.maxdb 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.725
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.725
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.webservice_1.1.201.v200807240600.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.webservice 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.725
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.726
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.3.101.M20080805_34x.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help.webapp 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.726
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.726
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.web_1.1.206.v200812100430.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.web 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.726
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.web 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.726
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-06-08 15:28:34.727
.
.
.
.
.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions on the eclipse folder in your application folder.  Make sure your second user has full read and write access.  Don't forget to apply the permissions to all items in the folder.